# node.js library that verifies an argument signature list?

Tags: node.js

Is there a node.js library that verifies arguments list to check if they conform to the arguments I want.

Like here's a function I want to write:

```
function my(a [,b], done);
```

`a` is required, and should be an object. `b` is optional but should be an array. `done` is the callback and should be a function.

Is there a library that would do all the necessary checks and substitutions (`if(!done)done=b`) etc automatically?

Comment: Is switching to TypeScript not an option here?

Comment: @DeerHunter That only works as long as the script is used in a TypeScript-only environment, i.e. when TypeScript's type checking system has the ability to run at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's three that I found;

### typed-function

```
var typed = require('typed-function');

// create a typed function
var fn1 = typed('number, *': function (a, b) {
  return 'a is a number, b can be anything';
});
```

https://github.com/josdejong/typed-function

### check-args

```
var accept = require("check-args-lib")

var fn = accept(Number).accept(String).to(function(dyna) {
  // do something with dyna...
  // If the type checking is enabled, you can now be sure it is
  // defined and it is a number or a string
});
```

https://github.com/artarf/check-args

### argue

```
var argue = require('argue');

function foo() {
  var sig = argue(arguments);
  switch(sig) {
    case 'sbnf':
      var mystr = arguments[0];
      var mybool = arguments[1];
      var mynum = arguments[2];
      var myfunv = arguments[3];
      // we got a string, boolean, number, and function
      break;

    case 'nnnn':
      // we got four numbers
      break;

    case 'ord-':
      // we got an object, regexp, date, and null
      break;

    default:
      // you get the idea
  }
}
```

https://github.com/ifit/Argue

I'd say I like `check-args` most out of the three as it provides a way to remove this sort of code in production very easily. `typed-function` has a pretty nice syntax, and `argue` is alright too, but is more like a helper for doing things like `typeof` checks than actually throwing any error.